# What is the best profiler for python multiprocessing, gevent, greenlets?

Tags: python, profiling, newrelic, greenlets, dynatrace

I am trying to profile my script which uses multiprocessing and spawn greenlets in several pools. 
I tried several libraries which came as a result in Google search but nothing is considerable.

I am looking at a profiler which gives all the basic resultnothing advanced.
I tried using GreenProfiler, cProfile, gevent_profiler etc.
Do any apm tools like new Relic , Dynatrace etc gives code level stats in python supporting multiprocess, greenlets ?

Answer (score 0):

5 years since the original question and the situation is still the same. I tried tools like **[New-relic](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/apm-ui-pages/events/thread-profiler-tool/#agent-thread-profiling),** **Datadog** and **[Amazon Code Guru Profiling](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-codeguru-profiler-python-demo-application/tree/main/sample-demo-flask-app#run-the-service)** - none seem to support profiling Gevent (Greenlets). The [greenlet docs](https://greenlet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tracing.html) are also not encouraging.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you try [Intel® VTune™ Amplifier](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe) (disclaimer: I work on it :) ).

It gained Python support last year, and it should be able to give you an overview of what's going on in your application along with line-by-line information, as well as certain details of what's going in the native part of your application should you want such info.

Oh yeah... note that if you're an active Open Source contributor or want to use it for educational purposes, you might be eligible for a [free license](https://software.intel.com/en-us/qualify-for-free-software).

#IamIntel